# C++ tuple implementation with get as a member

Tags: c++

If you're familiar with std::tuple, you're aware that accessing its elements is slightly unusual. Instead of using a member function, we're provided with the function `std::get` instead. I was curious as to why this is, so I conducted a brief search. The few websites that I saw all gave the same reason: the code used to called the method is ugly.

We would expect:

```
my_tuple.get<0>()
```

but apparently we would have to write:

```
my_tuple.template get<0>()
```

([a source, see footnote 5](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/)).

This seemed like a bad case of "I heard that she heard that he heard...", because I was unable to find an implementation of a tuple that exposed this ugliness by including get as a member. I heard that Boost's tuple had get as a member, but after inspecting the source I discovered that it also only accepted 10 elements max. It was time for me to implement it myself!

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Tuple
{

};

template <std::size_t Index, typename... Rs>
struct TypeHolder;

template <std::size_t Index, typename R, typename... Rs>
struct TypeHolder<Index, Tuple<R, Rs...>>
{
    typedef typename TypeHolder<Index - 1, Tuple<Rs...>>::type type;
};

template <typename R, typename... Rs>
struct TypeHolder<0, Tuple<R, Rs...>>
{
    typedef R type;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class Tuple<T, Ts...> : public Tuple<Ts...>
{
public:
    Tuple(T obj, Ts... objs)
        : Tuple<Ts...>{ std::forward<Ts>(objs)... }
        , obj{obj}
    {

    }

    template <std::size_t Index>
    typename std::enable_if<
        Index == 0,
        typename TypeHolder<Index, Tuple<T, Ts...>>::type&
    >::type get()
    {
        return obj;
    }

    template <std::size_t Index>
    typename std::enable_if<
        Index != 0,
        typename TypeHolder<Index, Tuple<T, Ts...>>::type&
    >::type get()
    {
        return static_cast<Tuple<Ts...>*>(this)->get<Index - 1>();
    }

protected:
    T obj;
};
```

This functions as expected, and after some brief testing I found that there were no issues with storing pointers or references. But there was no need to write "template" for every call to get! (My compiler is GCC, by the way.)

Is there a reason why `std::tuple` was not implemented in this way? I would like to know about any glaring flaws with this code before I move forward with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source is not very specific as to why/when `my_tuple.template get<0>()` is required.

If you have code like this:

```
Tuple<int, double, float> x(1,2,3);
int i = x.get<0>();
```

That is fine, because all template arguments to `Tuple` are known at the time of parsing and `Tuple<int, double, float>` is instantiated immediately, before the call to `get` is parsed. At that point the compiler already knows that in that specific instantiation of `Tuple` `get` is member function template rather than a non-template member and everything is ok.

This however

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T t) {
    Tuple<T,int,double> x(t,2,3);
    return x.get<0>();
}
```

generates a compiler error, because when `foo` is parsed, the actual type of `T` is not known and instantiation of `Tuple<T,int,double>` needs to be delayed until instantiation of `foo`. This means that when `x.get` is parsed, the compiler does not yet know what kind of language construct `get` is in the instatiation of `Tuple<T,int,double>` and in fact it may very well vary for different `T`. Therefore it is assumed that `get` is a non-template member, which doesn't make sense considering the following template argument list.

Your code sadly does not solve this problem and I don't think it is solvable.

Additionally I noticed that your `Tuple` is an empty class if an empty type list is given. That is a bit inconsistent. I think at least `get` should be provided as empty function. Calling it should not be allowed, but referring to the member function should be fine.

Comment: I see! In your second block of code, changing the return line to  `return x.template get<0>()` results in successful compilation, but that is exactly what everyone was seeking to avoid.

Comment: @user118534 Yes exactly. I think it is categorically impossible to avoid that. It is required by the standard for all template members on dependent types.

Comment: That could be a resaonable explanation as to why there's no member `get` in the standard **instead** of the helper function - but doesn't explain why you can't have both. The problem is that a free function requires sometimes struggles with namespaces and symbol conflicts, and this problem with the member happens only in very rare cases - in which you can simply use the free function, if member's usage is so ugly.